# Newsletter "Win Stuff" section should highlight that eligibility is limited to the US

Tags: discussion, newsletter

I just got a mail from Stack Overflow with the topic "[Quarterly Update] Making Stack Overflow more welcoming".

At the end is a section "Win Stuff" which made me curious. So I checked it read a little about each and then I tried to take part. Then I found that this is limited to US only. Why don't you mention that?

Comment: How did you find out when it wasn't mentioned?

Comment: @Hans if you click the link in the mail you'll go to https://contests.stackoverflow.com/, and when you click one of the two available actions, you'll have to check a box "I live in the United States" to apply.

Comment: That's strange; I didn't receive such an email. If I had, I'd be interested too in winning stuff (I still need a mug) and I'd be frustrated too at not being in the US.

Answer (score -25, accepted):

Not all contests are always limited to the US. For example, the Bluemix content was only open to residents of India.

The section in the email was simply to advertise our new contests page where you can keep an eye out for new contests you might be able to participate in. It is relevant to everyone, not just those in the US.

Comment: "Not everything is for the US, we had one thing for India too" - Well then I guess it's only irrelevant for the other 193 countries.

Comment: @Seinop Don't be so crude. We have no idea what kinds of contests others will want to host in the future or what countries they may or may not be limited to. As well, that was an example. There has been more than one contest not limited to the US (and some not limited *at all*). It *is* still relevant to everyone. Stop taking meaning from words where no meaning was intended.

Comment: I get what you mean, but as someone genuinely interested in the contests seeing ones I cannot participate in is pointless. I would not have signal boosted that page to everyone as something to check out right now unless there was at least one international contest taking place.

Comment: Doesn't this highlight that it should be made more obvious, seeing how now everyone is affected rather than just us plebeian non-us citizens? I feel like this answer misses the point.

Comment: @Shadow Make what more obvious, exactly? The entire point of that section appearing was "we built a new contests page, take a look." It didn't mention the ongoing contests at all, and as far as I know, we have no plans to continue including it in every singe email update. This was a product announcement email, and we had a new page that people might be interested in, and so it was included. The link in the email even explicitly says "Bookmark contests page" because we want it to be a thing you come back and check, without implying that you will be able to participate in something *right now*.

Comment: @animuson this user attempted to take part before realising it was US only. I just had a look at the contents page myself, and you can't tell from the lists which ones you are eligible for. I guess my suggestion would be that eligibility by region is just as important as the time the competition runs for - and thus could be put in the same area on the main page.

Comment: @Shadow I mean, including the country/countries which are eligible in the card for an active contest sounds like a useful feature request if you want to post it. But this question was focused on the product update including mentions of contests that were supposedly not relevant to everyone, whereas the focus of the email was on the existence of the page, not the individual contests. Feel free to post a new feature request.

Comment: I get what you mean now. Fair enough.

Comment: Let's say it from my perspective 100% of the viewed contests where US only.

Comment: I opened the page. Then I had to *click every single* (ok, there's only two) *contest, only to find out after completely reading it, I am excluded*. Sorry, but if you want to exclude me, tell me upfront. Once you show me the menu, you better serve me.

Comment: @animuson The process flow for most international users: Open the link. Waste some time looking at a few contests only to eventually find out they're all US only. Close the page. Never think about it again. You seem overly optimistic if you think people who don't see a contest they're even eligible for is going to come back to the page. If you want non-US participators, there should be an international contest at announcement. Even just to win like a mug or something. And you should be able to see eligibility from the main page without having to go to the individual contests.

Comment: @Dukeling for the [Not a Robot badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) they also never bothered adding something you can subscribe to. *"We update this frequently, so stay tuned for more events closer to you."* straight out of the 90s.